# How can I communicate which object (within an ArrayList) a clicked node is attributed?

Tags: java, class, user-interface, arraylist, javafx

I am making a JavaFX form program.  The form data is handled using an ArrayList of Pages which are ArrayLists of Nodes, which are objects containing the GUI element (label) and it's data members.
Like so:

***Main Declaration***

```
private final ArrayList<ArrayList<FormNode>> form = new ArrayList<>(); 
private final ArrayList<FormNode> page = new ArrayList<>(); 
int currentNode = 0;  //index of currently active node
```

***Object Class***

```
public class FormNode {

    private String nodeName;
    private boolean visible;
    private boolean editable;
    private Label nodeGUI;

    //Constructor...Sets...Gets...Methods

}
```

When the node is initialized, it is added to a pane and assigned event handlers via a separate class. What I am trying to do is have the program communicate which object is active by clicking on the node that is associated with it, so it can be flagged as the active node.

Something like this (not really my actual code, just pseudo of what I need):

The user clicks on the desired label (node) in the GUI, which calls...

```
nodeGUI.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override public int handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

      --- call a method to assign the value ---
        currentNode = thisNodesIndex;


    }
  });
```

The idea is to return the index of the FormNode object in the nested page ArrayList to assign `currentNode` that value.

Right now everything works fine, but accessing the index is the trouble.  Data is accessed from the Label itself (x, y, height, width, etc) but I need it to be recognized as a member of the object so I can manipulate the other attributes. (i.e `nodeName`, `visible`, etc).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know If I truly understand what you are asking, but try this.

```
@Override
public void handle(Event evt) {
   System.out.println(((Control)evt.getSource()).getId());
}
```

In your case:

```
nodeGUI.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public int handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        //--- call a method to assign the value ---
        currentNode = thisNodesIndex;
        System.out.println(((Control)mouseEvent.getSource()).getId());
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear.  I'm basically asking how to do things a little backwards, I suppose.  Where as someone might access a variable or attribute of an object in an arraylist by accessing the arraylist in a specific index, I want to know which object (at what index) a certain attribute originates.  In this case, a node in a gui (button, label, etc).  If I click on it, I want to get the object it's in.  So, if I click on the 3rd label created, I can tell it is the label contained in the object at `form.get(3)`. I'm looking to get a 3 returned.

Comment: I will try your suggestion, and see if it's what I'm looking for.  Thanks